# Http Request Post with your wanted ID in couchbase sync gateway

Tags: node.js, request, couchbase

My couchbase server is set with sync gateway so i need to use "request" module to make a http request to do POST request.

If i don't specify my id, my code is working to POST a JSON to my server 
If i would like to POST my document with my wanted ID, i cannot POST it with the warning shown below

```
{
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "reason": ""
}
```

My Code is as follows:

```
//routes.js 
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var couchbase =require("couchbase");
var request = require("request");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
var Rule = require("./RuleDao").Rule;

var appRouter = function(app){
    app.post("/rule/:id", function(req,res){

        Rule.save(req.params, options3, function(error, result){

            if(error){
                return res.status(400).send(error);
            }
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Then Dao.js is as follows:

```
//Dao.js
Rule.save = function (data, options, callback){
     var options ={
        method: 'POST',
        headers: 
        { 
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        json: true 
     }
     var id = data.id; 
     var path= '/eabbre-dev/'+ id; 
     var url = 'http://192.168.222.150:4984/mybucketName/' +id;
     var json = data.json; 

     // update options here !!! 
     options.url=url;
     options.body = json; 

    request(options, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return callback(error, null);
        }
        callback(null, result.body);
    });
```

}

Comment: Unrelated, but you should remove your auth credentials from the question.

Comment: Hopefully eabuser:AAbb1122 is just for dev purposes and not what you use in production :)